# Unable to select data via read only transaction

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle and SQL Developer. I have a table called `T_TEST` owned by `SYSTEM` (I know, that I shouldn't do it, but it's not a commercial project). I created another user and gave him this privileges:

```
GRANT CONNECT TO admin1;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO admin1;
GRANT SELECT ON T_TEST TO admin1;
```

When I run this query I get the expected result:

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM SYSTEM.T_TEST;
```

However, when I try to wrap this query in a transaction like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE reader
AS
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY;
    SELECT SUM(value) FROM SYSTEM.T_TEST;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

I get this error:

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

So which privilege am I missing here?

Comment: You might not have the privilege to create procedures.

Comment: Why do you `SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY`, if all you do is read from a table anyway? And why `COMMIT` when you don't change any data? Apart from that your procedure is invalid. You read the sum of all values but where to? You must have an `INTO` clause to select that value into a variable. Then, what do you want to do with this sum? Your procedure doesn't produce any output. Sorry, all this doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yeah, I know, that I need an INTO clause, but I simplified my procedure for the sake of the question. As for transactions, I am very new to this concept. However, I've seen multiple examples of read only transactions with commit in the end. I need to make sure, that every select I do is a separate transaction, so I figured I just set the transaction manually.

Comment: This behaviour, select works in `SQL`, but not in `PL/SQL` is typicall if you grant the privilege to a *role* and not to the user....

Comment: a select (unless for update or similar) does not create any transaction.  there is nothing to commit.  Whatever examples you looked at, are wrong.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber But admin1 _is_ a user, not a role. I agree with Ankit Bajpai above that I probably lack the privilege to create a stored procedure. However, I have no idea how to grant that in Oracle.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I looked the example here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems047.htm So I guess the difference is that they use `dbms_output.put_line`?

Comment: @Vladislav Oh I see now.  Yeah that is to reset the prior transaction mode selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing grants to create a procedure. You can do that by following the below command -

```
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO [domain\user]
```

This [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/GRANT.html#GUID-20B4E2C0-A7F8-4BC8-A5E8-BE61BDC41AC3__BABEFFEE) has a whole list of permissions that you can grant to the users. Enjoy your project.